# mySQL Equavalent for Oracle utl_http.request

Tags: mysql, sql, xml, web-services, oracle

I want to be able to call a web feed or service every X amount of time. I was wondering if there was a mySQL Equivalent for the Oracle [utl_http.request](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_http.htm) functionality. I know that I could do the same with a cron job and some server side scripts, but is it possible to do this within a mySQL database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the closest you will find is storing it down and having a 3rd party in your architecture listen for it like the cron job examples you've probably found on the web.

Sorry for the bad news, oracle has a lot of toys.  ;)

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything. It would have been easier if such was possible, but a cron job with a php script shouldn't be much more difficult.